# Parametric equation of a straight line in Misner, Thorne and Wheeler

Tags: coordinate-systems, parametric

On page 49 of *Gravitation* by Misner, Thorne and Wheeler they talk about the different ways of representing a vector in spacetime. In Box C they give the equation for a parametrised straight line between points A and B as
$$P\left(\lambda\right)=A+\lambda\left(B-A\right)$$
At my high-school-type maths level, I don't recognise this equation. For example, for the straight line
$$y=3x+7$$
I would write $x=t$ and $y=3t+7$. So how to understand $P\left(\lambda\right)=A+\lambda\left(B-A\right)$? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You would pick two points from the line $y=3x+7$, say, the intercept $A=(0,7)$ and some other point like $B=(1,10)$, when the difference vector is $B-A=(1,3)$. Then you can rewrite the line in parametric form
$$(x,y)=(0,7)+t(1,3),$$ which, of course describes exactly the same set of points. Different choices for $A$ and $B$ will result in different parametrization of the line (think of the parameter as giving tick marks on the line). The line (as a set of points) remains the same.

Comment: And that works using any coordinate system? I've just briefly tried polar coordinates and they seem to work OK.

Comment: @Peter4075 Any _orthogonal_ coordinate system, I hasten to add. It even works in polar, but parametrised "lines" in $r,\theta$ will become spirals and roses and all sorts of beautiful curves.

Comment: You might also see this parametrization in the form of the *affine combination* $(1-\lambda)A+\lambda B$. This form emphasizes the point of view that every point on the line is a weighted sum of the two representative points $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(\lambda)$ is parametrised by $\lambda$, where $\lambda=0$ corresponds to $A$ and $\lambda=1$ to $B$. The points for other $\lambda$ values are defined by linear interpolation between $A$ and $B$ – for example $\lambda=\frac34$ corresponds to a point $\frac34$ of the way from $A$ to $B$, while $\lambda=-1$ is $B$ reflected about $A$.

The main advantage of this representation is its structural invariance under coordinate transformations (whereas the slope/intercept form depends on axes and fails on vertical lines). This is important in the context of Misner, Thorne and Wheeler, where general relativity bends the local coordinates of spacetime. It lets them treat worldlines between events, among other things, in a unified manner.

Comment: So when you say "The main advantage of this representation is its structural invariance under coordinate transformations", you don't mean the line will remain straight if the coordinate system is changed, just that it will continue to join points A and B?

Comment: @Peter4075 Yes. The _form_ of the equation remains the same, but not necessarily what it represents. It will still join its two endpoints.

Comment: I've just experimented with two endpoints in polar coordinates and ended up with a curve. That's neat.